# Shared border between polygons with Geopandas

Tags: geopandas, borders

How could I measure the shared border of a polygon with other polygons in Geopandas?
The result could be an n x n matrix of polygons with the longitude of the segment of border they share.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it with this function:

```
def shared_boundary(file):
    polys = fiona.open(file)
    shared = []

    for pol1, pol2 in  itertools.combinations(polys, 2):
        geompol1 = shape(pol1['geometry'])
        geompol2 = shape(pol2['geometry'])
        if geompol1.touches(geompol2):
            length = shape(mapping(geompol1.intersection(geompol2))).length
            shared.append([tuple(pol1['properties'].items())[0], tuple(pol2['properties'].items())[0], int(length)])
    
    shared = list(zip([x[0][1] for x in shared],
                  [x[1][1] for x in shared],
                  [x[2] for x in shared]                  
                 ))
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(shared, columns=['poly1', 'poly2', 'length']).sort_values(by=['poly1', 'poly2'])
    df = df.loc[df.length > 0].reset_index(drop=True)

    return df
```